# VSCode Docker extension cannot connect to docker machine

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm unable to configure the VSCode `Docker` extension by Microsoft to connect to a `docker-machine` via setting of the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable.

[image: Docker extension instructions]

**.zshrc**

`export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"`

**I have:**

1. Run `source ~/.zshrc` and restarted VSCode
2. Logged out and reopen VSCode

Has anyone else run into this issue before and found a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 2376 in your `DOCKER_HOST` implies your docker daemon is most likely running on TLS.

Assuming it is, you also need to set a `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` environment variable.

On my (default Windows) installation, its value is `C:\Users\mike\.docker\machine\machines\default`.

This does seem like a glaring omission from [the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker#connecting-to-docker-machine), so I went ahead and [raised a PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker/pull/324).

Comment: awesome! This worked like a charm :) Great idea creating the PR.